# bezier control point orientation d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm hand cranking a network diagram from D3 (I didn't like the output of Force Directed). To do this, I've generated an array of nodes, each with an x/y co-ordinate.

```
{
    "nodes" : [
        {
            "name" : "foo",
            "to"   : ["bar"]
        },
        {
            "name" : "bar",
            "to"   : ["baz"]
        },
        {
            "name" : "baz"
        }
    ]

}
```

I then generate an svg, with a parent svg:g, and bind this data to a series of svg:g elements hanging off the parent.

```
addSvg = function () {
    // add the parent svg element
    return d3.select('#visualisation')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);
};

addSvgGroup = function (p) {
    // add a containing svg:g
    return p.append('svg:g').
        attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)');
};

addSvgNodes = function(p, nodes) {
    // attach all nodes to the parent p data
    // and render to svg:g
    return p.selectAll('g')
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append('svg:g')
        .attr('class', 'node');
};
```

Then I manually position the nodes (this will be dynamic later, I'm just getting my feet)

```
transformNodes = function (nodes) {
    // position nodes manually
    // deprecate later for column concept
    nodes.attr('transform', function (o, i) {
        offset = (i + 1) * options.nodeOffset;
        // options.nodeOffset = 150
        o.x = offset;
        o.y = offset / 2;
        return 'translate(' + offset + ',' + offset / 2 + ')';
    });
};
```

Then I attach these items to the parent svg:g, and hang some text off them. 
This results in a staircase of text descending left to right within the svg. So far, so good.

Next, I want to generate some links, so I use a method to determine if the current node has a relationship, and then get that nodes location. Finally, I generate a series of links using d3.svg.diagonal and set their source/target to the appropriate nodes. Written longhand for clarity.

```
getLinkGenerator = function (o) {
    return d3.svg.diagonal()
        .source(o.source)
        .target(o.target)
        .projection(function (d) {
            console.log('projection', d);
            return [d.x, d.y]
        });

};
```

Now, so far, so good - except the control handles for the bezier are not where I would like them to be. For example from node A to node B the path d attribute is thus:

```
 <path d="M150,75C150,112.5 300,112.5 300,150" style="fill: none" stroke="#000"></path>
```

But I'd like it to alter the orientation of the control handles - i.e

```
 <path d="M150,75C200,75 250,150 300,150" style="fill: none" stroke="#000"></path>
```

This would make it look more like a dendrograph from the page of examples. What I noticed in the collapsible dendrograph example is that it returns an inversion of the axes:

```
 return [d.y, d.x]
```

But if I do this, while the control points are oriented as I would like, the location of the points is out of whack (i.e their x/y co-ordinates are also reversed, effectively translating them.

Has anyone else encountered an issue like this or have an idea of how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I took a look at this and figured out a solution. It appears that some of the layouts (dendrogram, collapsed tree) are inverting the co-ordinates of source/target in the path links so that when they hit the projection call, they get reversed back into their correct location, but with the orientation of their bezier points rotated.

So, if you're hand cranking a custom layout and you want to orient the bezier controls horizontally (like the examples), that's what you need to do.